# Multi-named Vertices (or Overlapping Vertices) in TreePlot/LayeredGraphPlot, or Merging Trees

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, labeling, rule, trees

If there is a series of rules from which a `TreePlot`/`LayeredGraphPlot` is made:

```
{D->C, C->B, B->A}
```

And a new vertex is added that is technically the same as an existing vertex, but has an alternate name or alias, for instance, "Q", which is the same as "A", and we create a new rule:

```
{B->Q}
```

Is there a way in `TreePlot`/`LayeredGraphPlot` to combine Q and A into a single vertex with two names?  It seems that it should be possible to have aliases in `TreePlot`/`LayeredGraphPlot` that allow a vertices to point to other vertices that have more than 1 name.  Here is a graphical example of what I mean:

[image]

EDIT: An alternative way of viewing this question is merging 2 distinct trees but preserving all names and aliases of the linking vertex.

Comment: I think a few more examples might help.  I am interested, but I don't understand your needs well enough to attempt an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess what I am really asking is whether or not a vertex within a plot can have two simultaneous values, in the above case "A" and "Q".  Therefore, given the rules lists I mention in the post, rather than generating two different plots, combining them into one plot, in which the vertex in question has two names rather than one.  I'll update the post to change "node" to "vertex".  Also, I see this is something that could apply to `LayeredGraphPlot`, among others.

Answer (score 1):

```
treea = {D -> C, C -> B, B -> A};

treeb = {B -> Q};
```

Combine two trees based on starting vertex:

```
combined = 
  Flatten[GatherBy[Join[treea, treeb], First] /. 
    x : {a_Rule, b__} :> a[[1]] -> Row[Riffle[x[[All, 2]], "/"]]]
```

> {D -> C, C -> B, B -> Row[{A, "/", Q}]}

Decorating:

```
vshape[c : {xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := {
  Hue[0.6, 0.77, 0.8], 
  EdgeForm[{Hue[0.6, 0.77, 0.22], Thickness[.05]}], 
  Disk[c, {3 w, 2 h}]}

res = Graph[#, VertexShapeFunction -> vshape, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
     VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
     VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[13, White], 
     EdgeStyle -> Hue[0.6, 0.77, 0.8], 
     GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
       "Orientation" -> Bottom}, VertexSize -> .2, 
     ImageSize -> 50] & /@ {treea, treeb, combined};

Row[{res[[1]], Spacer[50], "+", Spacer[50], res[[2]], Spacer[50], 
  "->", Spacer[50], res[[3]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you handle `treeb = {Q -> B}` instead?

Comment: @Carl Woll you could use the similar technique: Flatten[GatherBy[combined, Last] /. 
  x : {a_Rule, b__} :> Row[Riffle[x[[All, 1]], "/"]] -> a[[2]]]

Comment: Or `treeb = {Q->B, A->R}`? Or `treeb = {Q<->B, A->R}`. My point is that using `GatherBy` instead of graph operations like `VertexContract` or `VertexReplace` seems a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Carl Woll yes, can be. But to use VertexContract or VertexReplace you need to find out what vertices you want to operate anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
edges1 = {"D" -> "C", "C" -> "B", "B" -> "A"};
edges2 = {"B" -> "Q"};

options = {GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> "D", 
      "Orientation" -> Bottom}, 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Thick, Arrowheads[.1], Arrow[#1, {0, .1}]} &), 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium};

g1 = Graph[edges1];
g2 = Graph[edges2];
g3 = GraphUnion[g1, g2, ## & @@ options, ImageSize -> Medium];
g4 = SetProperty[
   VertexContract[g3, {"A", "Q"}], {VertexSize -> {"A" -> Medium}, 
    VertexLabels -> {"A" -> Placed["A/Q", Center]}, (options /. 
      Arrowheads[_] :> Arrowheads[.5]), ImageSize -> Medium}];

Row[{g3, g4}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @kglr's answer is to use [`VertexReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace). Your original [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph):

```
g = Graph[
    {"D"->"C", "C"->"B", "B"->"A", "B"->"Q"},
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> "D", "Orientation" -> Left},
    VertexLabels->"Name"
]
```

[image]

Use [`VertexReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace) to identify both "A" and "Q" as "A/Q":

```
new = VertexReplace[g, Thread[{"A","Q"}->"A/Q"]];
```

And view the result:

```
Graph[new, VertexLabels->"Name"]
VertexList[new]
```

[image]

{"D", "C", "B", "A/Q"}